# Confusion regarding connecting nport in cadence while trying to find input impedance

Tags: circuit-analysis, cadence, s-parameters, schematic

I am a little bit confused on how to to connect the nport in the case where I try to find looking in impedance of a transmission line which is loaded by a 1pF capacitor on the one side.
As shown in the figure there are different ways of connecting the nport instance,

[image]

Can you please explain which is the correct configuration and why?

Comment: They might all be correct but, what you are trying to achieve may or may not suit one or all connections. Only you know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Andy, I'm trying to find the looking in impedance, when looking to P1 side.